# My android studio app keeps crashing after using a background method to read a json from my fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am making an app using the Kitsu API. Here in this moment I have a fragment that allows me to search different anime using the api to get information such as name, synopsis, etc. After parsing the information I proceed to go back to my main activity to pass it to my new fragment, but it crashes the moment I initialize the method to go back to my main activity. My question is how do I use a fragment to read a JSON with a background class using ASYNCTASK and display it in a new fragment?

I have noticed that it jumps around a lot from my fragment, in an activity different from my main, to a class running in the background, to my main, to my fragment. Below are images of my code. Thank you very much.

[Search fragment code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZ4iV.png), [Main Activity search related methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDPj6.png), [Search results background tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNYAm.png), [Search Results Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2Y4f.png). To clarify It stops before I get to the string I labeled crashpoint and doesn't make it to the search results fragment. I felt like it would be handy to have that bit of code in there. [Here is the error I get with my code when I run it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0yVw.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new fragment after reading JSON. Just to post an simple code that read JSON with async task:

```java
package com.example.compsci_734t;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;



public class People extends Activity{

        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
        static InputStream is = null;
        //private static String url = "";
        //private static String url = "http:...";
        private static String url = "http....";
        //URL requestUrl = new URL(url);
        JSONArray people = null;
        private static final String TAG_COURSES = "Courses";
        static JSONObject jObj = null;
        static String json = "";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.people);
            new MyTasks().execute();
        }


        private class MyTasks extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, JSONObject> {

            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(URL... urls) {
               // return loadJSON(url);
                try {
                    // defaultHttpClient
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    //HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    is = httpEntity.getContent();

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              try {
                /*BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "UTF-8"), 8);*/
                InputStream inputStream = is;
                GZIPInputStream input = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(input);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                   //System.out.println(line);
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            // try parse the string to a JSON object

            try {

                JSONArray people = new JSONArray(json);
                //JSONArray people = new JSONArray(json);

                for (int i = 0; i < people.length(); i++) {
                    //System.out.println(courses.getJSONObject(i).toString());
                    JSONObject p = people.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String person_id = p.getString("someString1");


                    items.add(person_id);

                    /*Log.v("--", "People: \n" + "\n UPI: " + person_id);*/
                }


                //jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            } 

            // return JSON String
            return jObj;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
                ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.peopleList);
                myListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items));
   }
}
```

The sample code was taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16519523/parsing-json-url-using-async) answer.

Comment: My parsing isn't the problem. My problem is that after I parse the JSON I want to use that information. Since I'm new to using JSON's I figured I either make another fragment and go from there or a new activity. My app crashes when I try to initialize my method that puts me back into the main.

Comment: after you parse JSON data (from REST service?), you will invoke method `onPostExecute` on the main thread to update the UI.

Comment: After more testing I found that I can pass my bundle to the main, but it crashes the moment I try to pass my information that I got from my main into the my search results fragment. It crashes on the t.commit() line. I tried having my background task use my other activity, the activity where the fragment takes place, but it won't allow it. If you're wondering my main is a login screen that goes to a new activity.

Comment: I have just added the error I get when I run the code.